# Javascript: XMLDocument iteration

Tags: javascript, xmldocument, domparser

I have the following code:

```
var xmlString = ajaxRequest.responseText.toString();
parser = new DOMParser()
doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
```

The response text is a complete HTML document. After I create the XMLDocument (doc), I want to go over each node, manipulate some stuff and print it.

How can I iterate the XMLDocument? I want to go on each one of its nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little example if you want to get all links from this XML and print their text

```
var links = doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i=0;i<links.length;i++)  {  
    var txt=links[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    document.write(txt + '<br>');
}
```

Almost sure that this is correct, didn't had time to test it.

You may read this articles to go deeper:

[getElementsByTagName](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementsByTagName)

[nodeName](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeName)

[NodeList](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/NodeList)

Hope this helps.

Best regards!